# UINavigationViewController memory releasing

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

First of all, i have never seen so many memory issues in my app since i started placing "self" everywhere after reading an article about how memory behaves in obj-C. Now, im getting all kinds of issues (reveals the sloppiness of my coding). Granted I am a newbie at Objective-C, i'll admit i have never had so much issues with memory management before in my life. But i reckon it takes practice to get used to this.

Now, on to my question.

I have a class interface property (self.todoCreate) that holds a reference to the above controller. This controller is navigated to by pressing a button.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) TodoTaskCreateController *todoCreate;
```

The code below are the snippets that cause the navigation view change:

```
TodoTaskCreateController *viewController = [[TodoTaskCreateController alloc] 
                   initWithNibName:@"TodoTaskCreateController"
                            bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

self.todoCreate = viewController;
[viewController release];
// slide-in todoCreate controller.  
if (self.navigationController != nil && self.todoCreate != nil) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.todoCreate animated:YES];
}
```

So here is my problem:

The first time i run this it works.
Once I'm on the second view screen, I navigate back to the main view.
And if i try to navigate again a 2nd time, then the app crashes, right where `self.todoCreate` is being assigned `viewController`.

Note that within the main view's `viewDidAppear` method, I call `[self.todoCreate release]`.

Can anyone explain this?

*PS - No wonder so many iPhone apps randomly crash.*

Answer (score 1):

`todoCreate` is a property, which means when you assign a value to it, it invokes a method called `setTodoCreate` which looks something like:

```
- (void) setTodoCreate:(Foo*) newVal
{
    [todoCreate release]; // release the previous object
    todoCreate = [newVal retain]; // point to new object, and also retain it
}
```

Now your `viewDidAppear` method is releasing `self.todoCreate` at which point the retain count of `todoCreate` is 0. When you create a new `TodoTaskCreateController` and assign it to `self.todoCreate` another `release` is performed, but this time on an object with retain count of 0.

Instead of `[self.todoCreate release]`, you should be using `self.todoCreate = nil`.

You probably shouldn't be continually destroying and creating your `TodoTaskCreateController` either.

Your comment regarding application crashing is most likely due to developers not testing their application to see if it handls memory warnings properly. In the simulator there is a menu option to simulate this, and your application should "survive" the warning in *all* of its views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to speak to soon, but it APPEARS that i have resolved the crash by simply adding the viewController to the autorelease pool, and then removing all manual occurances of its release.

Now does it matter if my @property for createTodo is defined as (nonatomic, retain) as opposed to (nonatomic, assign)?

Comment: If you do `self.todoCreate = <something>` with a `retain` property, the old value will be released; if you do the same with an `assign` property, the old value will not be released.

Comment: Wait a minute, i thought it was behave exactly the opposite from the way your described. Since retain increments the reference count, wouldnt a property described with retain be NOT released? Yet again, just when i thought i got the hang of things, something like this shakes my understanding of it. Very frustrating.